# ReferenceError: gethostname is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, system, server-name

I tried to assign a var with `gethostname()` [(1)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php) and with `$_SERVER`[(2)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and I keep on getting `ReferenceError: gethostname is not defined`.

All I want is to get the current system name into a var using JS which runs in my PHP. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

```
var myVar = gethostname();
```

or

```
var myVar = $_SERVER;
```

Comment: could you please share the actual code here including how you are using it in JS

Comment: `gethostname` isn't a JavaScript function, and `$_SERVER` isn't a JavaScript variable.  You need to learn the *difference* between server-side and client-side languages.  PHP runs on the *server* and generates an HTML page (with JavaScript).  Then it quits.  It sends the HTML to the browser and exits.  The client has no idea that PHP generated the file, all it knows it that it has some HTML to render and some JavaScript to run.  If your PHP file is generating this JavaScript you can try this: `var myVar = '<?php echo gethostname(); ?>';` and `var myVar = <?php echo json_encode($_SERVER); ?>;`.

Comment: i think u got the answer from @RocketHazmat

Comment: Hey guys this is about php not javascript read the title befor you comment @RocketHazmat

Comment: @FrankfromDSPEED: `ReferenceError: gethostname is not defined` is a JavaScript error, not a PHP error.  `var myVar = gethostname();` is JavaScript code, not PHP code.  I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: How about instead of bashing each other, you'll see if you can come up with a way to combine the two?

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: Can you show us your *actual* PHP code?  The code that creates these 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I approached this whole issue a little differently, and my initially approach was wrong to begin with.

I decided to get the IP address by executing

```
$ipAddress = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
```

Then I wanted to get the host name, so I did a shell execution:

```
$myArg = "nslookup $ipAddress";
```

Eventually I used `stripos` to get the start ("name = ") and end ("domain.name") positions of the host name, and eventually I used `substr` to get the hostname out.

I will use the result to pass it to the JS.

Answer (score 0):

thats clear it says that there is no code like "function gethostname()" that means it cant work if you try to get the hostname via the var you try to get

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

echo $hostname;
?>
```

this would get the hostname of the server where the script is running on!

since $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is the own servers ip address

```
<?php 
//Gets the IP address
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") ; 
Echo "Your IP is " . $ip; 
?>
```

will get the ip of the user that runs the script since getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") contains the ip of the user

Comment: The problem here is that he is trying to call `gethostname()` from JavaScript.  `ReferenceError: gethostname is not defined` is a JavaScript error, not a PHP error.